# Maxscript find specific vray material in the scene

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I cant seem to get array of some types of vray materials. For example i can get default VRay Mtl with

mat = for m in scenematerials m.category == #VRay collect m

but if i try to collect  #VRay2Sided or #VrayBlend it returns an error.
Do they have different flags and if yes, where can i find full documentation of vray material flags?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. VRay2Sided and VRayBlend are standard category so to get them you need to write

```
mat = for m in scenematerials m.category == #standard collect m
```

And if you are not sure which category some material is just type it in listener

```
materialName.category
```

and it will print out its category